# wso2 unable to install a feature using pom

Tags: maven, ant, wso2, wso2-api-manager

Getting a build failure when I'm trying to install a feature using the `pom.xml`.
WSO2 API Manager 2.6.0.
Latest versions of apache maven and ant installed.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>org.wso2.sample</groupId>
  <artifactId>sample-feature-installation</artifactId>
  <version>1.0.0</version>
  <packaging>pom</packaging>
  <name>New feature</name>
  <url>http://wso2.org</url>
  <build>
    <plugins>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.wso2.maven</groupId>
        <artifactId>carbon-p2-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.5.4</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <id>feature-install</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
              <goal>p2-profile-gen</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
              <profile>default</profile>
              <metadataRepository>http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/</metadataRepository>
              <artifactRepository>http://product-dist.wso2.com/p2/carbon/releases/wilkes/</artifactRepository>
              <destination>wso2am-2.6.0/repository/components</destination>
              <deleteOldProfileFiles>false</deleteOldProfileFiles>
              <features>
                <feature>
                  <id>org.wso2.carbon.hl7.feature.group</id>
                  <version>4.6.6</version>
                </feature>
              </features>
            </configuration>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>1.1</version>
        <executions>
          <execution>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <configuration>
              <tasks>
                <replace token="false" value="true" dir="wso2am-2.6.0/wso2/components/default/configuration/org.eclipse.equinox.simpleconfigurator">
                  <include name="**/bundles.info"/>
                </replace>
              </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
              <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
          </execution>
        </executions>
      </plugin>
    </plugins>
  </build>
  <repositories>
    <repository>
      <id>wso2-nexus</id>
      <name>WSO2 internal Repository</name>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/groups/wso2-public/</url>
      <releases>
        <enabled>true</enabled>
        <updatePolicy>daily</updatePolicy>
        <checksumPolicy>ignore</checksumPolicy>
      </releases>
    </repository>
  </repositories>
  <pluginRepositories>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven-releases-repository</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/releases/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
    <pluginRepository>
      <id>wso2-maven-snapshots-repository</id>
      <url>http://maven.wso2.org/nexus/content/repositories/snapshots/</url>
    </pluginRepository>
  </pluginRepositories>
</project>
```

> [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:p2-profile-gen (feature-install) on project sample-feature-installation: P2 publisher return code was 13 -> [Help 1]
>   org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.wso2.maven:carbon-p2-plugin:1.5.4:p2-profile-gen (feature-install) on project sample-feature-installation: P2 publisher return code was 13
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:215)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:156)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute (MojoExecutor.java:148)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:117)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject (LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:81)
>       at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build (SingleThreadedBuilder.java:56)
>
> [ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/MojoExecutionException

Comment: It seems a matter of certificates. Try with this link: http://mail.wso2.org/mailarchive/dev/2016-April/062035.html

Comment: That shouldn't e the problem as I've followed this documentation: 
https://docs.wso2.com/display/Carbon430/Installing+Features+using+pom+Files